Why are these C functions optimized differently by GCC?
I am writing embedded code for an ARM Cortex-M processor. I wanted some generic function to copy memory to registers that are mapped contiguously into memory.
Since the C standard forbids aliasing arbitrary types, I thought I would simply copy the buffer byte-wise, and let the optimizer figure out whether the arguments are properly aligned (or whether they even need to be stored in memory), hopefully resulting in decent code gen.
This is the function:
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef volatile uint32_t reg_t;

static inline void copyToReg(reg_t* dest, const void* src, size_t len, bool read_modify_write)
{
    const unsigned char* const src_bytes = (const unsigned char*) src; // when the function is inlined and src is properly aligned the
                                                     // byte wise copying could be optimized away?
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len / 4; i++) {
        uint32_t value = 0;

        value |= src_bytes[i * 4 + 0];
        value |= src_bytes[i * 4 + 1] << 8;
        value |= src_bytes[i * 4 + 2] << 16;
        value |= src_bytes[i * 4 + 3] << 24;
        //value = ((const uint32_t*) src)[i];

        dest[i] = value;                             // volatile write
    }

    size_t remainder = len % 4;

    if (remainder != 0) {
        uint32_t finalValue;

        if (read_modify_write)
            finalValue = dest[len / 4];              // volatile read

        finalValue &= 0xFFFFFFFFU << (remainder * 8);

        for (size_t j = 0; j < remainder; j++)
            finalValue |= src_bytes[len - remainder + j] << (j * 8);

        dest[len / 4] = finalValue;                  // volatile write
    }
}

However I am getting mixed results testing code gen.
The following two test functions:
extern const uint32_t buffer[4];
reg_t x[8];

void test1() {
    copyToReg(x, buffer, 8, false);
}

void test2(const uint32_t* buf) {
    copyToReg(x, buf, 8, false);
}

are compiled differently by gcc 13.3.0 with -O3 (godbolt):
test1:
  ldr r2, .L3
  ldr r3, .L3+4
  ldm r2, {r1, r2}
  str r1, [r3]
  str r2, [r3, #4]
  bx lr
.L3:
  .word buffer
  .word .LANCHOR0
test2:
  str lr, [sp, #-4]!
  ldrb r2, [r0] @ zero_extendqisi2
  ldrb lr, [r0, #1] @ zero_extendqisi2
  ldrb ip, [r0, #2] @ zero_extendqisi2
  orr r2, r2, lr, lsl #8
  orr r2, r2, ip, lsl #16
  ldrb ip, [r0, #3] @ zero_extendqisi2
  ldrb r3, [r0, #4] @ zero_extendqisi2
  orr r2, r2, ip, lsl #24
  ldrb ip, [r0, #5] @ zero_extendqisi2
  ldr r1, .L7
  orr r3, r3, ip, lsl #8
  ldrb ip, [r0, #6] @ zero_extendqisi2
  str r2, [r1]
  ldrb r2, [r0, #7] @ zero_extendqisi2
  orr r3, r3, ip, lsl #16
  orr r3, r3, r2, lsl #24
  str r3, [r1, #4]
  ldr lr, [sp], #4
  bx lr
.L7:
  .word .LANCHOR0
x:
  .space 32

Clang behaves similarly.

Why could this be? I would expect that the compiler is allowed to assume that the pointer to uint32_t is properly aligned, and emit the same code.

Does the C standard forbid the optimization in the latter function for some other reason or is this a shortcoming of clang and gcc, and if yes why might that be given that they are able to optimize the first function?

Are there are other ways of writing the function to more reliably achieve good code-gen, like manually checking for alignment, or would it be better to write my own assembly at that point?



Sidenote: Isn't extern const uint32_t buffer[4]; supposed to be 8 elements considering that is the len passed to copyToReg?

Sidenote: You are reading uninitialized finalValue when read_modify_write == false. Initialize finalValue.

Sidenote: src_bytes[i * 4 + 3] << 24; is shifting with signed type which means you are shifting into sign bit. Use unsigned shift.

One thing that stands out to me is that test1 can see that arguments don't alias, but test2 does not. (I am not 100% sure how volatile affects aliasing in this case).

Hmm okay I tried this on a bunch of targets and the problem seems specific to the ARM32 ports of gcc and clang. On x86 I either get identical or nearly identical code for both versions.

@ikegami I get about the same as that when merely switching the OPs code to x86_64. restrict doesn't seem to matter.

Looks like an optimizing bug in the arm-none-eabi port. I can't think of any other explanation. Linking the code with the Linux ABI, same compiler version & same options solves the problem.

-march=armv7 also fixes the problem. Don't ask me why.

Yes, with certain -march and -mcpu options, it seems to work. although interestingly the assembly is annotated with "@unaligned", and as far as I can tell the options where it doesn't work are exactly the ones where the architecture doesn't allow unaligned access (e.g. -march=armv6-m or -mcpu=cortex-m0). So it seems changing those doesn't make the compiler assume that the address is aligned, but rather it doesn't care about producing unaligned access instructions.

Some more experiments without the pointer casting result in the same behavior: https://godbolt.org/z/anr9MWvfM

I guess this is kind of a solution, although I'm not happy really with having to resort to a macro https://godbolt.org/z/34bcahTs8

@Gizzzmo You could attempt to report it in Bugzilla as a missed optimization bug in the ARM32 none-eabi port of gcc. Either it is a bug or otherwise perhaps someone reading those bug reports got an insight of why the -march= option makes a difference.

You can use manual alignment if you want.
Declare in the function that the parameter is aligned by using __builtin_assume_aligned(). And ensure that pointer your send into function is aligned by using __attribute__((aligned())).
So your code will look something like this:
static inline void copyToReg(reg_t* dest, const void* src, size_t len, bool read_modify_write)
{
   dest = __builtin_assume_aligned(dest, 8);
   src = __builtin_assume_aligned(src, 8);
   .... no changes to remainder of the function
}


int main() {
   reg_t dst[4] __attribute__((aligned(8)));
   reg_t src[4] __attribute__((aligned(8)));
   test2(dst, src, sizeof(dst), false);
}


That doesn't answer the question "Why are these C functions optimized differently by GCC?"

Well if I knew that the pointer was always aligned, I would just make the function take a const uint32_t* instead of const void*, and not do the copying byte-wise. I was hoping that, with the function being inlined, the optimizer could this figure this out by itself, and as the first test shows it can, but apparently not consistently.

They're optimized differently because the underlying generated C code is different.
In test1(), buffer and x are known "constants"(I have "constants" in quotes because clearly the address could be anything, but it is resolved to a constant at link time).
Because the function copyToReg() is inline, all of the code generated there knows the exact address of what it's manipulating (because the global variables that are located at link time are the symbols that are used in the inline code) and the optimizer can fold and optimize to its heart's content.   In this case, it sees the addresses are aligned, and very possibly replaces register loads with constant loads since it knows this addresses.
In test2(), the addresses of the buffer are passed in, so when it uses copyToReg() to generate the code, it all operates on register contents and the opitimizer/compiler knows much less about the buffers and addresses and so have fewer tools available.
In particular, test1() knows the two buffers' alignments and can make assumptions from that.    test2(), because it has no idea what the alignment is, must follow the code as written.
And your code has the comment right in it:
// when the function is inlined and src is properly aligned the
// byte wise copying could be optimized away?

But to answer your questions:

Why would you expect a uint32_t* to be an aligned pointer?  Also, the parameter of the inline function is a void* which is then cast to a uint8_t*   There's nothing there that says "this pointer must be aligned", and the C or C++ spec doesn't dictate that pointers are aligned.

I'm going to say that the language doesn't so much "forbid" as there's not enough information available to the compiler in the second case to make the optimizations you want while maintaining the results that expected from the written code.

You can write the alignment check in the code, but that code will be generated and executed so test1() will still be higher optimized than test2() because the toolchain is doing all of those checks for you (since it knows the alignment during compiler/link) and only writing out the code required to meet the expected output given that input.   test2() will never have that amount of information and will have to do runtime alignment checking before jumping to the aligned implementation vs. the unaligned implementation.



None of this explains why the two versions generate identical code on for example gcc 14.2 arm-linux-eabi but different machine code in gcc 14.2 arm-none-eabi.

"Why would you expect a uint32_t* to be an aligned pointer?" I thought this was the default behavior? If the compiler can't assume that pointer to x is x-aligned then isn't this wrong code gen: https://godbolt.org/z/jEoYhs6zz? If the pointer is unaligned the generated assembly will lead to an unaligned acess

@user3022568 Since I got the problem to disappear when compiling with a specific target setting or just switching ABI, it does actually seem as if it is related to alignment. Because without knowing the specific target then maybe the compiler can't make any assumptions of if it is capable of misaligned access or not. That's the best explanation I have other than compiler port bug.

@Lundin, the question was not "why does this compile differently on these two compilers", the question was "why do these two functions compile differently".   This answer answers that question explicitly.

@user3022568 The C and C++ standards do not dictate a pointer is aligned.   They do dictate that a pointer returned from allocations is aligned.   This is why the test1() is able to assume the alignment (because the compilation unit sees the symbols that it's accessing are defined as declared instances, thus aligned).   Test2() cannot do that because it is passing those pointers through a forwarding function which hides their origin from the optimizer.

@Lundin to answer "why this compiler vs. that one", I'd guess the default settings of some of the compilers are providing different optimizations.   in test2(), it's possible the compiler is recognizing that it's just a forwarding shim.  Another option is that in linux, unaligned accesses are cleaned up via exceptions (sounds horribly slow), OR they assume the processor specified by arm-linux-eabi can do unaligned accesses.  Another option is the default architecture for arm-none-eabi and arm-linux-eabi are different.

@RussSchultz: The C++ standard is irrelevant, since this question is not for C++. The C standard allows means by which a pointer might be constructed without the alignment required for its referenced type, but the only correct values for a pointer to object type are a null pointer and a correctly aligned address. A compiler may optimize on the basis that (given the pointer is not null since memory is accessed with it) either the pointer is correctly aligned, so optimizing for that is allowed, or the pointer is incorrectly aligned and the behavior is not defined, so any optimization is allowed.


Why could this be? I would expect that the compiler is allowed to assume that the pointer to uint32_t is properly aligned, and emit the same code.

In test1(), you are passing a global variable to copyToReg(), and in test2(), you are passing a pointer argument.
From the view of ARM assembly language, in case of test1(), it seems that the compiler can assume it is properly aligned and is safe to perform direct ldr (load) and str (store) instructions, avoiding byte-wise accesses.
However, in case of test2(), the compiler performs byte-wise access and then combines the bytes manually into a 32-bit word using bit shifts due to the compiler probably cannot be certain that the pointer passed to copyToReg() is correctly aligned to a 4-byte boundary.

Are there are other ways of writing the function to more reliably achieve good code-gen, like manually checking for alignment, or would it be better to write my own assembly at that point?

What you can try to improve the code generation for both cases is to avoid void* for the src argument and use const uint32_t* instead.
static inline void copyToReg(reg_t* dest, const uint32_t* src, size_t len, bool read_modify_write) {
    ...
}

If you know that buf is always aligned, what you can also try to use __builtin_assume_aligned() to explicitly inform the compiler that the pointer is aligned to 4 bytes.
void test2(const uint32_t* buf) {
    const uint32_t* aligned_buf = (const uint32_t*) __builtin_assume_aligned(buf, 4);
    copyToReg(x, aligned_buf, 8, false);
}

